# Quartz.NET - Using/understanding cron based trigger and time zone/summertime (daylight saving time)

Tags: c#, timezone, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

For sake of an example lets use the following cron expression: "0 0 14 1 * ?"
-> Fire on the 1st day of every month at 14:00 hours.

I used the Quartz CronScheduleBuilder to build the expession, but this is irrelevant.

My Local timezone is UTC+01:00 and the summertime (this year) begins on 31.03.2013 2:00, where the time is adjusted to 3:00.

When i schedule a new Job using the proposed trigger on lets say 20.02.2013, Quartz calculates the System.DateTimeOffset for the "NextFireTimeUtc" correctly to:
DateTime: 01.03.2013 13:00:00 (this is the UTC time, which is one hour behind the local timezone)
LocalDateTime: 01.03.2013 14:00:00

The job will correctly trigger on 14:00 hours as specified.

Now if i schedule the job on 20.03.2013, the "NextFireTimeUtc" results in:
DateTime: 01.04.2013 13:00:00 (this is the UTC time, which is now two hours behind the local timezone)
LocalDateTime: 01.04.2013 **15:00:00**

Notice, that the resulting NextFireTimeUtc now falls within the local summertime. As a result, the LocalDateTime was also "corrected" by an additional hour from the UTC. This results in the job running at 15:00 hours, which is not what i want.

What i (obviously) expected is that the "14" in the cron expression should always result in the trigger firing at 14:00, even during summertime.

There must be an easy way to deal with this phenomenon, i am probably just missing something conceptional. I am confused.

**EDIT:**
The problem seems to be, that Quartz calculates the **first** NextFireTimeUtc depending on the **current** timezone information. To test this, i scheduled two different cron triggers and called GetFireTimeAfter() on the trigger with an increasing offset to view the resulting fire times over the year.

Trigger 1: Fire on the 28th of every month at 14:00

> GetFireTimeAfter now + 00 months: 28.03.2013 **13:00:00 +00:00** <- this is correct
>   GetFireTimeAfter now + 01 months: 28.04.2013 12:00:00 +00:00
>   GetFireTimeAfter now + 02 months: 28.05.2013 12:00:00 +00:00
>   GetFireTimeAfter now + 03 months: 28.06.2013 12:00:00 +00:00
>   GetFireTimeAfter now + 04 months: 28.07.2013 12:00:00 +00:00
>   GetFireTimeAfter now + 05 months: 28.08.2013 12:00:00 +00:00
>   GetFireTimeAfter now + 06 months: 28.09.2013 12:00:00 +00:00
>   GetFireTimeAfter now + 07 months: 28.10.2013 13:00:00 +00:00 <- summertime already ended
>   GetFireTimeAfter now + 08 months: 28.11.2013 13:00:00 +00:00

The first fire time is correct, since it still falls into "wintertime". The times during "summertime" are off by an additional -1, resulting in the correct fire time after the local timezone adds +2.

Trigger 1: Fire on the first day of every month at 14:00

> GetFireTimeAfter now + 00 months: 01.04.2013 **13:00:00 +00:00** <- this is wrong?
>   GetFireTimeAfter now + 01 months: 01.05.2013 12:00:00 +00:00
>   GetFireTimeAfter now + 02 months: 01.06.2013 12:00:00 +00:00
>   GetFireTimeAfter now + 03 months: 01.07.2013 12:00:00 +00:00
>   GetFireTimeAfter now + 04 months: 01.08.2013 12:00:00 +00:00
>   GetFireTimeAfter now + 05 months: 01.09.2013 12:00:00 +00:00
>   GetFireTimeAfter now + 06 months: 01.10.2013 12:00:00 +00:00
>   GetFireTimeAfter now + 07 months: 01.11.2013 13:00:00 +00:00 <- summertime already ended
>   GetFireTimeAfter now + 08 months: 01.12.2013 13:00:00 +00:00

The first fire already falls within summertime, but its only offset by -1, resulting in a local trigger time of 15:00.

So the trigger is fine, except for the first trigger time, if its scheduled during wintertime and the first execution falls within summertime. How to handle this?

Comment: If UTC is +2 at that date/time, and you give it 13:00 UTC it will correctly add 2.  You're not asking it to do something at 14:00 local, you're asking to do something at 13:00 UTC.  If you want something to happen at a specific local time, in this instance, you'll have to either calculate which UTC time you want to use, or do something like 12:59 UTC...

Comment: The problem seems to be, that Quartz calculates the first NextFireTimeUtc depending on the current timezone information. If its still wintertime and the NextFireTimeUtc falls within summertime, its off by one hour. See my edit in the original post.

Comment: How are you calculating the  times in your update?  Are you simply getting the current `NextFireTimeUtc` then successively adding to that one value?

Comment: I use `trigger.GetFireTimeAfter(DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMonths(i))` where i is incrementing in a for loop.

Comment: @PeterRitchie: You may want to take a look [at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15682441/1790864). I illustrated the problem in a unit test.

Comment: Okay, but is that how Quartz.Net does the calculation for the next date?  If it's not, then what you've displayed for dates/times is irrelevant...

Comment: I don't know if the underlying mechanism from `GetFireTimeAfter()` is exactly the same that the Scheduler uses, but it would make sense and (at a glance) it shows the same behavior (after all, i noticed it using the scheduled trigger in the first place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that this actually is a bug in Quartz.NET 2.0.1, but it has already been fixed in 2.1.0.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15689395/1790864) for details.