# Quartz.NET - Shouldn't this unit test pass?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, timezone, quartz.net, dst

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15661268/1790864), but is kept more general and can be treated independently.

EDIT: Quartz version is v2.0.1

From my understanding, the following unit test should pass:

```cs
[Test]
public void Test() {
    // run every first day of month at 14:00 hours
    CronExpression expression = new CronExpression("0 0 14 1 * ?");

    //  TimeZoneInfo.Local = {(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rom, Stockholm, Wien}
    if (!TimeZoneInfo.Local.SupportsDaylightSavingTime) {
        return;
    }

    // get "summertime" period for current timezone
    var daylightChange = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetDaylightChanges(2013);
    //  -> daylightChange.Start     {31.03.2013 02:00:00}   System.DateTime
    //  -> daylightChange.End       {27.10.2013 03:00:00}   System.DateTime

    // get one startpoint before and one after begin of summertime
    DateTimeOffset beforeSummertime = daylightChange.Start.ToUniversalTime().AddDays(-1);
    DateTimeOffset afterSummertime = daylightChange.Start.ToUniversalTime().AddDays(1);
    // -> beforeSummertime  {30.03.2013 01:00:00 +00:00}    System.DateTimeOffset
    // -> afterSummertime   {01.04.2013 01:00:00 +00:00}    System.DateTimeOffset

    DateTimeOffset? nextValidTimeFromBefore = expression.GetNextValidTimeAfter(beforeSummertime);
    DateTimeOffset? nextValidTimeFromAfter = expression.GetNextValidTimeAfter(afterSummertime);
    // nextValidTimeFromBefore  {01.04.2013 13:00:00 +00:00}    System.DateTimeOffset?
    // nextValidTimeFromAfter   {01.04.2013 12:00:00 +00:00}    System.DateTimeOffset?

    Assert.AreEqual(nextValidTimeFromBefore, nextValidTimeFromAfter);
}
```

However (as you can see), the `nextValidTimeFromBefore` differs from `nextValidTimeFromAfter`. The result in `nextValidTimeFromAfter` is correct. The UTC 12:00 will result in 14:00 during summertime (which already started at that point).
It shouldn't matter if the `GetNextValidTimeAfter()` parameter specifies a time inside or outside of the summertime period.

Should the NextValidTimes be equal or is my approach flawed?

Comment: This passes fine for me (I'm not in your TZ) and if I just create a new `DaylightTime` object with the start and end dates you've detailed (e.g. `daylightChange = new DaylightTime(new DateTime(2013, 3, 31, 2, 0, 0), new DateTime(2013, 10, 27, 2, 0, 0), TimeSpan.MinValue)`) it passes as well.

Comment: Thanks, this encouraged me to take another look at the newer Quartz versions. I already checked the change-log on the site, which does not mention a related fix. However, when i looked through the commits in the repository i noticed there actually was a fix for this. I will add an answer with detailed information.

Comment: I tried this with 2.1.2.400, FWIW

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured out that this actually is a bug in Quartz.NET 2.0.1, but it has already been fixed in 2.1.0.

I checked the change-log on the site, which does not mention a related fix. The comment from Peter Ritchie encouraged me to take another look at the newer Quartz versions. When i looked through the commits in the repository i noticed there actually was a fix for this.

It has been fixed in revision 665:

> Merge pull request #72 from amazing-andrew/master
>   Time zone issues with CronExpression, calendars, CalendarIntervalTriggerImpl

The first official release that contains this fix is v2.1.0, which was tagged at revision 685.

The bug was located in `CronExpression.GetTimeAfter()` (which is called by `CronExpression.GetNextValidTimeAfter()`):

```
...
d = new DateTimeOffset(year, d.Month, d.Day, d.Hour, d.Minute, d.Second, d.Offset);

// apply the proper offset for this date (this wasn't there)
d = new DateTimeOffset(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day, d.Hour, d.Minute, d.Second, this.TimeZone.GetUtcOffset(d.DateTime));
...
```