# Force Quartz.NET to Work in UTC?

Tags: cron, quartz.net

This is kind of related to [Quartz.NET - Shouldn't this unit test pass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682441/quartz-net-shouldnt-this-unit-test-pass/15689395#15689395), but not exactly.

I have a server in GMT-4 and one in GMT-7. They both use Quartz.NET v2.1.2.400. I need both server do the same thing at the same time (within a little tolerance) based on GMT, using this cron string:

```
0 0 5,12,17 * * ?
```

However, one server is executing the job this before the other server. I need them to both be in sync. I am using the code below. I think that Quartz calculates times/schedules in GMT internally but externally does localtime. I want it to be GMT all the time. How can I do that?

My current code looks like this:

```
var trigger = new CronTriggerImpl(mytriggername) { CronExpressionString = cronString };
var job = new JobDetailImpl(jobName, jobType);
Quartz.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `setTimeZone` method in the java implementation of CronTrigger and a `TimeZone` property in the .NET implementaion.

You can then set the timezone for the trigger on both matchines to UTC.

Of course this will only work if the server clocks on your machines are synchronised in some way, using NTP or similar.