# Quartz.Net ITrigger Showing wrong Hour

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler

I'm working with Quartz.net trying to make a event trigger from Tuesday to Saturday at 8:30am.

I use the following code to define the trigger time

```
IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<DailyAutomationProcess>().Build();
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithCronSchedule("0 30 8 ? * TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT *").Build();
        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        scheduler.Start();
```

The "0 30 8 ? * TUE,WED,THU,FRI,SAT *" is generated from http://www.cronmaker.com/.

But for some reason during run-time when I check ITrigger trigger it shows the wrong time.
It shows the "nextFireTime: 12/01/2017 16:30:00 +00:00}"

The hour seems always wrong.

And if the next firing hour is 16:30 the firing date should be 11/30(today) since it is not 16:30 yet.

I'm confused here any suggestion can help.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: CK my Quartz.Net is on 2.6.1

Edit:The following is my Application_Start

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ScheduledTasks.DailyAutomationTrigger();
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Quartz are you using? Looks like a bug in Quartz.NET 2.0.1, but it has already been fixed in 2.1.0,Have a look at [Quartz.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682441/quartz-net-shouldnt-this-unit-test-pass/15689395#15689395)

Answer (score 0):

I totally forgot the time is UTC time shown on next firing time.
And the event firing just fine now.
Sometime need to rebuild the solution to make sure it got a new firing time table