# Quartz.net Create daily schedule on UTC time

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I'm trying to fire a job every morning at 8AM, UTC time. The problem is the triggers aren't respecting the time I'm telling it.

My code is as follows:

```
    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(
             s => s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
                 .OnEveryDay()
                 .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(8,0)))
        .Build();

   var times = TriggerUtils.ComputeFireTimes(trigger as IOperableTrigger, null, 10);

   foreach (var time in times)
       Console.WriteLine(time.UtcDateTime);
```

The output is:

```
30/09/2013 10:00:00 PM
1/10/2013 10:00:00 PM
2/10/2013 10:00:00 PM
3/10/2013 10:00:00 PM
4/10/2013 10:00:00 PM
5/10/2013 10:00:00 PM
6/10/2013 9:00:00 PM
7/10/2013 9:00:00 PM
8/10/2013 9:00:00 PM
9/10/2013 9:00:00 PM
```

The reason the hour changes on the 6th is that daylight savings time starts here this weekend.

How do I get it to just trigger at 8AM UTC time like I'm telling it to?

Edit: This is crazy, it even does it with the Cron schedule:

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithCronSchedule("0 0 8 * * ?")
    .Build();

var times = TriggerUtils.ComputeFireTimes(trigger as IOperableTrigger, null, 10);

foreach (var time in times)
    Console.WriteLine(time.UtcDateTime);
```

Output:

```
30/09/2013 10:00:00 PM
1/10/2013 10:00:00 PM
2/10/2013 10:00:00 PM
3/10/2013 10:00:00 PM
4/10/2013 10:00:00 PM
5/10/2013 9:00:00 PM
6/10/2013 9:00:00 PM
7/10/2013 9:00:00 PM
8/10/2013 9:00:00 PM
9/10/2013 9:00:00 PM
```

Comment: Which version of quartz.net are you using? Maybe this post is related to your issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15661268/quartz-net-using-understanding-cron-based-trigger-and-time-zone-summertime-da

Comment: Quartz.Net 2.2 for 4.0 (2.2.400.0)

Comment: According to that question there was a bug in GetFireTimeAfter() that used local time to create trigger dates. That seems to be the behaviour I'm seeing. That question mentions a fix in Quartz.Net 2.1, but I'm running 2.2, so it could be a new variation on that bug (or I could be doing something wrong).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After pulling down the source code and digging through, I've found a couple of solutions.

I originally found a solution like so:

```
var trigger4 = new DailyTimeIntervalTriggerImpl
{
    StartTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
    StartTimeOfDay = new TimeOfDay(8, 0, 0),
    RepeatIntervalUnit = IntervalUnit.Hour,
    RepeatInterval = 24,
    TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Utc
};
```

...which led me to adjust my original code:

```
ITrigger trigger2 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(
        s => s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
            .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(8, 0))
            .InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Utc))
    .Build();
```

Both of these give me what I'm after. I just wish there was some decent documentation out there for this library.

Comment: Are there any unwanted/unknown side effects changing a running system from Local to Utc?

Answer (score 7):

Though this is old, I'll answer it here anyway.  You can simply perform the operation of:

`ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithCronSchedule("0 0 8 * * ?", cron => { cron.InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.Utc); } )
    .Build();`

Comment: So the default is the local time zone? And not UTC?

Comment: @Ozkan Yes, it runs as per the system timezone. That's why as per the docs, you can choose a different timezone, please refer to docs [here](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/tutorial/crontriggers.html#building-crontriggers)